# unsigned char array to unsigned int back to unsigned char array via memcpy is reversed

Tags: c++, c

This isn't cross-platform code... everything is being performed on the same platform (i.e. endianess is the same.. little endian).

I have this code:

```
    unsigned char array[4] = {'t', 'e', 's', 't'};

    unsigned int out = ((array[0]<<24)|(array[1]<<16)|(array[2]<<8)|(array[3])); 
    std::cout << out << std::endl;

    unsigned char buff[4];
    memcpy(buff, &out, sizeof(unsigned int));

    std::cout << buff << std::endl;
```

I'd expect the output of buff to be "test" (with a garbage trailing character because of the lack of '/0') but instead the output is "tset."  Obviously changing the order of characters that I'm shifting (3, 2, 1, 0 instead of 0, 1, 2, 3) fixes the problem, but I don't understand the problem.  Is memcpy not acting the way I expect?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because your CPU is [little-endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). In memory, the array is stored as:

```
      +----+----+----+----+
array | 74 | 65 | 73 | 74 |
      +----+----+----+----+
```

This is represented with *increasing* byte addresses to the *right*. However, the integer is stored in memory with the *least* significant bytes at the left:

```
    +----+----+----+----+
out | 74 | 73 | 65 | 74 |
    +----+----+----+----+
```

This happens to represent the integer 0x74657374. Using `memcpy()` to copy that into `buff` reverses the bytes from your original `array`.

Comment: Bah.  Smacks self in head.  Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You're running this on a little-endian platform.

On a little-endian platform, a 32-bit int is stored in memory with the least significant byte in the lowest memory address. So bits 0-7 are stored at address P, bits 8-15 in address P + 1, bits 16-23 in address P + 2 and bits 24-31 in address P + 3.

In your example: bits 0-7 = 't', bits 8-15 = 's', bits 16-23 = 'e', bits 24-31 = 't'

So that's the order that the bytes are written to memory: "tset"

If you address the memory then as separate bytes (unsigned chars), you'll read them in the order they are written to memory.

Answer (score 0):

On a little-endian platform the output should be `tset`. The original sequence was `test` from lower addresses to higher addresses. Then you put it into an `unsigned int` with first 't' going into the most significant byte and the last 't' going into the least significant byte. On a little-endian machine the least significant byte is stored at lower address. This is how it will be copied to the final `buf`. This is how it is going to be output: from the last 't' to the first 't', i.e. `tset`.

On a big-endian machine you would not observe the reversal.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a `'\0'` to your `buff`?

Answer (score 0):

You have written a test for platform byte order, and it has concluded: *little endian*.